# Flutter Workflow for saving & retrieving images

Tags: image, flutter, file, dart, provider

I am trying to build an app where the user can add images from [Image Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker), then save it in a [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) as well as in Firebase. For retrieving it should be the other way around: Get it from Firebase and then store it in my Provider.

(**ignore the Firebase part, for now I only want to store the images in a Provider, but it should be correctly set up, so I can add the Firebase support later**)

The problem is that I am quite new to Flutter and I am not how to start here, because there are so many ways to load images in Flutter. From the `ImagePicker` I retrieve a `File`. What is the correct way to store this in a Provider so I can load it in another screen?

I know this is quite a genreal question but I hope some one can shed some light in the dark for me here :D Let me know if you need any more info.

I already setup a `ChangeNotifier`:

```
class MemoryImageProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String path = '';

  setImage(String path) {
    path = path;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but save the returned File form ImagePicker in a File object(import dart:io). something like this:                                                                                `File? _selectedFile;

  File? get selectedFile => _selectedFile;

  void setSelectedFile(File file) {
    _selectedFile = file;
    notifyListeners();
  }`

Comment: @Xoltawn I guess I can do that, but I would like to store the image directly. I dont want to convert all the time.